# Django Model-is there any way to select multiple pages like checbox in wagtail panel?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, wagtail

How to select multiple pages instead of single page in wagtail?

In my code,i used  **link_page** which picks only one page

```
    class Collections(models.Model):
            heading = TextField(blank=True,)
            description = RichTextField(blank=True,)
            SelectResources = SortedManyToManyField(SelectResource)
            link_page = models.ForeignKey(
                'wagtailcore.Page',
                null=True,
                blank=True,
                on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                related_name='+'
            )

            panels = [
                FieldPanel('heading', classname="title"),
                FieldPanel('description', classname="full"),
                FieldPanel('link_page'),
            ]

            class Meta:
                abstract = True  
    class HomeCollections(Orderable, Collections):
            page = ParentalKey('Home', related_name='collections')
```

collections added to home as inline panel

```
class Home(AbstractForm):    
        content_panels = AbstractForm.content_panels +[
        InlinePanel('collections', label="collections"), 
        ]
```

Comment: This is a comment apart of this question, try to not use Collections as your model name. There is a module named Collections in the Python standard library (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html and https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/Collections.html) and could be confusing for others. Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [StreamField](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#freeform-page-content-using-streamfield) with a [PageChooserBlock](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#pagechooserblock). Something like this:

```
pages = StreamField([
        ('page', blocks.PageChooserBlock())
    ])
```